# OData V4 date comparison

Tags: api, odata, webapi

I need help with this issue. I have a backend with c# in Net Core 3.0 and I have a Machine entity with a series of attributes among them, 3 Datetime type entities.
(I have installed the NuGet package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 7.5.2')

In my database I have these entities with this type of format (Ex : AssemblyDate : 2014-02-27 00:00:00.000)

In my Postman I am trying to build the next OData consultation:
https://localhost:xxxxx/api/v1/Machine/OData?$top=11&$skip=0&$filter=AssemblyDate ge 2013-10-30T00:00:00.000Z

But the result I get is: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.OData.UriParser.ConvertNode' to type 'Microsoft.OData.UriParser.SingleValuePropertyAccessNode

I don't understand what the problem is. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the url in your example is the problem. You said that the entity that you are querying is the 'Machine' entity but the url you posted has an additional navigation of "OData" in it. Try:
`https://localhost:xxxxx/api/v1/Machine?$top=11&$skip=0&$filter=AssemblyDate ge 2013-10-30T00:00:00.000Z`

This assumes that the endpoint for the 'Machine' entity set is 'Machine'. However, the convention, as far as I am aware, is to make the endpoint plural so it may be 'Machines'.